# Good way to make a scroll site

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I wonder what is the best approach to make a "scroll site", that kind of graphical website which reacts when the user scrolls.

Like

http://www.evanshalshaw.com/bondcars/
or
http://www.angelamorelli.com/water/

Is it jQuery ? HTML5 ?

Is it a huge algorithm in a dummy `$(document).scroll()` function ?

Comment: it would be quiet simple jquery involving use of `$(document).scroll()` and jquery's animate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are JQuery plugins to help you make a "scroll site":

- http://johnpolacek.github.com/superscrollorama/
- http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/ (this one is used by the second site you provided)

And have a look at the javascript code of the sites you provided, to see how they did it.

Answer (score 1):

I have also used the scrollwheel plugin http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/docs.
With that, I was able to make scrollsites (hor and vertical) with absolute positioned elements. Also a nice addition to that is Tweenmax https://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/. Helped to make animations on the scroll input.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Does you first lib only responds to mousewheel? I think the animations should work also with scrollbar.

Comment: I actually used both:
The scrollwheel Plugin is used to calculate the speed (and other params, like direction) of the scroll and to have an event for my animations.

Then I use the $().scroll function to measure distances and align objects on the page (so it also works when scrolling with the scrollbar - which it doesnt would I only use the scrollwheel plugin).

Hope this makes sense somehow :)